# Is there a way I can duplicate the "look up" functionality of an HTML <select> with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an application that presents a table of data on a screen.

The table has an `Id` column, a `Description` column and a `Created By` column

Data comes from two javascript arrays:

```
var rowData = [{ id: 1, desc: 'A', createdBy: 1 },
               { id: 2, desc: 'B', createdBy: 6 }];

var users   = [{ id: 1, name: 'jeff' },
               { id: 2, name: 'jane' },
               [ id: 6, name: 'jake' }];
```

Here is the HTML I am using. Note that to display the `Created By` as a name I use a `<select>` that is source from the users array

```
<table>
   <tr data-ng-repeat="row in rowData">
      <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
      <td>
         <select
            data-ng-disabled="true"
            data-ng-model="row.createdBy"
            data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in users">
         </select></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Using a `<select>` seems to work but seems like a very messy way to implement the look up and I see a select drop down which is disabled where I would really just like to see the name as text.

Without making any changes to the source arrays is there a way that I could put this look up into code or some kind of a directive. Note that the `CreatedBy` data is read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just loop through the `users` list and find the `name` by `createdBy`:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CdqTN/

Create a function that accepts createdBy. Then match it in a for loop:

```
$scope.getUser = function (createdBy) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.users.length; i++)
        if ($scope.users[i].id === createdBy)
            return $scope.users[i].name;
    return '';
}
```

Then call it in your HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr data-ng-repeat="row in rowData">
      <td>{{ row.id }}</td>
      <td>
          {{ getUser(row.createdBy) }}
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will look into this and check out your answer. One thing I was thinking when looking at your code. Could I add in an exit into the loop once the name was matched. That way it would reduce the need to go to the end of the loop once a match was reached.

Comment: yeah you can. i've updated it. just return $scope.users[i].name;